# Jquery .one() function doesn't prevent multi click event during form input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#some-items").one("click", ".comment-form-gonder input", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").css("cursor", "wait");

    //this part inserts user comment to the written comments below with animation.

    ...
```

The problem is when I double click send button, comment are inserted twice. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Most likely your event bubbles up the DOM. Try, other than `preventDefault()` to call `e.stopPropagation()`. That will ensure that the event doesn't fire on other elements above the intended one.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing preventDefault(); and
disable the button to be sure by

```
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

```js
var n = 0
$( "div" ).one( "click", function() {
    n++;
    if (n % 2 == 0){
        $(this).text('Foo');
    }else{
       $(this).text('Bar');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Foo</div>
```

Comment: or `this.disabled = true`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `e.preventDefault();` within **[`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** handler, makes the form not able to prevent default behavior after the first type of `one('event')` is executed. After that, the same `event` will submit the form as supposed to.

Prevent default form submission using `on()` and do the rest stuff with `one()` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.comment-form-gonder input[type="submit"]')
    .on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    .one('click', function() {
        // This part executes only on first click:
        $("body").css("cursor", "wait");
        // rest of your code...
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/06jb08qo/4/)

You could also `disable` the submit input after first click, but in some cases may be desired to keep it *'clickable'* (f.ex to inform the user that he cannot submit the form twice). To do so, you could store *click* state in `data` attribute of the input and use that state later on:

```
$(".comment-form-gonder input[type='submit']").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).data('clicked') == 'clicked'){
        return alert('already submitted!');
    }
    // This part executes only on first click:
    $(this).data('clicked', 'clicked');
    $("body").css("cursor", "wait");
    // rest of your code...
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/06jb08qo/7/)